# Create a select with a struct within a list pyspark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following Dataframe View `df_view`:

```
+---+-----+
| b |  c  |
+---+-----+
| 1 |  3  |
+---+-----+
```

I needed to select this data to form a key with a list of structs.

```
{
  "a": [
    {
      "b": 1,
      "c": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

With the `select` below it only creates a struct but not the list

```
df = spark.sql(
  '''
    SELECT
      named_struct(
        'b', b,
        'c', c
      ) AS a
    FROM df_view
 '''
)
```

And after that I'll save to the database

```
df.write
  .mode("overwrite")
  .format("com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark")
  .options(**cosmosConfig)
  .save()
```

How is it possible to create a struct inside a list in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the struct in `array()`:

```
df = spark.sql(
  '''
    SELECT
      array(named_struct(
        'b', b,
        'c', c
      )) AS a
    FROM df_view
 '''
)
```